# How to sort one particular field in collection?

Tags: oop, collections

I've created an Arraylist for Employee class and initialized values for the data members like Empid,Empname,DOJ,Salary...after initializing I want to sort with respect to any one particular field. Is this possible in collections or in any concept? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you learning 3 languages at a time?

Comment: oops is common for many programming languages right?

Comment: You can't write this so it will work in all three lanaguages. You have to pick one.  BTW There are lots of pages on how to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: @SanmugaNathan Yes, but it meaning is pretty vague and means different things to different people. If You only want a vague and boad answer I can give one, but I suspect it won't be very useful.

Comment: @Peter Im learning .net..Im expecting a good answer so I tagged related to oops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using c# and Linq you can try with:

```
var List = TheList.OrderBy(p => p.Empid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that linq(in **c#**) has this orderby extension method

```
List<MyObj> ol = myList.OrderBy(myOb => myOb.AProperty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java**:

If you always want to sort on the same field, have your class `Employee` implement `Comparable<Employee>`. Than you can use [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

If you want to sort on different Field, implement different [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) classes and use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

... In C#, this is very easily doable via [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) - Also look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for more examples.